# Dynamically change sap.ui.table row binding behaviour

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

There is requirement to change behaviour of **sap.ui.table** depending on no. of rows present in backend being binded to table and a threshold value set.
So if no. of rows are less than threshold value, then load all rows data and sorting/filtering done in browser i.e **operationMode** *Client*.

But if large no. of rows present exceeding threshold value then load with **$top/$skip** and sorting/filtering should trigger backend call i.e. **operationMode** *Server*.

As per documentation **operationMode** *Auto* should have worked but it keeps the sorting/filtering always on Server side irrespective of few rows present which are less than threshold value and so not working purely as *Client* **operationMode**.

Is there a direct way in XML view binding to change **operationMode** to Client/Server depending on count condition or **operationMode** injected conditionally in

```
<Table id="myTable"  threshold="200" visibleRowCount="10"  minAutoRowCount="10" 
rowHeight="40" 
visibleRowCountMode="Interactive"
rowSelectionChange="onTableChange" 
rows="{path: 'SampleEntitySet', parameters: {expand: 'Test123', operationMode : 'Server'}, events: {change: '.onTableChange'}}">
```

Please help in suggestion to solution. Thanks

Comment: operationMode "Auto" is supposed to work exactly as you need. Can you please check what is your operationCount mode?

Comment: @Cmdd Countmode I have tried with both Request and Inline, but still client behaviour not shown when sorting/filtering

Comment: I'm sorry for the silly question but... did you check if count is correct? I mean, the number of rows retrieved by the count is correct? I'm not a backend expert (AT ALL) but I learned to not take for granted all the stuff that comes from the backend :-)

Comment: Yes $count is correct for all cases

Comment: Mmmm ok. Where do you configure both modes? I usually put them in the manifest, at the model level.

Comment: Also, did you set a threshold on your table? Default value is 100

Comment: @Cmdd i have updated the complete table tag being used in above question, please check.

Comment: countMode is in manfest as Inline, tried with Request also but same incorrect issue of sorting/filtering being done on server for all cases irrespective of threshold value being surpassed or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245076/discussion-between-cmdd-and-mudassir-hasan).

Answer (score 4):

The question points to `OperationMode.Auto` (https://ui5.sap.com/1.102.1/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.OperationMode) which had been pointed out in a comment already. However, that `OperationMode` is not fully functional (likely since a long time) and is deprecated as of SAPUI5 1.102.

It makes sense to understand why you want to have such a differentiation in behavior. `OperationMode.Client` can be used as an optimization in case the data volume is small. This will mostly optimize the load caused on the backend. The user may not be aware of the difference unless the network to the backend is bad. And even the load for sorting or filtering on the server is not a real issue if the data volume is small.
So the question is whether there is actually another issue hidden behind the question and it makes sense to work on that issue.

Answer (score 1):

The "threshold" should be defined as a [binding parameter](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.OperationMode), not as a [property for the table](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Table%23methods/getThreshold). e.g.

```
oTable.bindRows({
    path : "/Categories",
    parameters: {
        operationMode : "Auto",
        countMode : "Inline",
        threshold: 9
    }
})
```

Please see the jsbin below and set the threshold property less than 8 to see the batch request for the sorting of the CategoryName column (Server mode) or set it bigger than 8 to see the Client mode in action.
https://jsbin.com/wutiyudoru/1/edit?html,output